Radzen Popup appears at the bottom of the page
I'm using the Radzen Popup component but the popup content appears at the bottom of the page below the footer.
This is my code below:
<RadzenButton @ref=button Text="Pop Up" Click="@(args => popup.ToggleAsync(button.Element))" />
<Popup @ref=popup Lazy="true" Open="@OnOpen">
                
    <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
        <RadzenButton Text="tes1" />
        <RadzenButton Text="tes2" />
    </RadzenStack>
                
</Popup>

@code {
    RadzenButton button;

    private Popup popup;

    async Task OnOpen()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", "setTimeout(function() {}, 200)");

    }
}

I'm using server-side render mode. Does anyone know what did I miss here?

According to the Radzen Popup demo, you can customize the position of the popup displayed with the Style attribute by providing the CSS rule.
If you want to display the popup in the center of the webpage or in a specific position, the key point is position: absolute.
<Popup @ref=popup Lazy="true" Open="@OnOpen"
    Style="display:none; position:absolute; height:300px;width:600px;">
                
    <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical">
        <RadzenButton Text="tes1" />
        <RadzenButton Text="tes2" />
   </RadzenStack>
</Popup>

